# Array of strings initialization in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

i know i can initialize like this

```
std::string foo [3] = {"T1","T2","T3"};
```

but what if declared it before do i have to initialize each one by its own? 
example

```
std::string foo [3];
foo[0] = "T1"
foo[1] = "T2"
foo[2] = "T3"
```

i mean giving the string all the values at once foo ={"T1","T2","T3"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you cannot initialise it after the declaration. The nuance is important, because in your second example you assign to the individual strings. Now, you want to assign to the whole array, which doesn't work. If you used a more intelligent data structure like `std::vector` you could indeed assign all values in one instruction, because the vector would throw away the old strings and create new ones that would be copy constructed from your `"T1"`,.. strings.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i wanted to know

Answer (score 1):

> what if declared it before do i have to initialize each one by its own?

You are not initializing each one by its own. They are initialized to the empty string (default constructed), and you are then assigning values to them.

Comment: yeah i know they are initialized to become empty strings but i want to initialize them all at once

Comment: @andrewmag: You're now saying two different things. It now seems like you want to initialize them to empty strings in one place and then initialize them to non-empty strings someplace else. Do you want to initialize them twice? Or do you want to later change their values?

Comment: no i dont want to initialize them twice i just want to declare them and then assign them the value once example foo= {"T1","T2","T3"}

Answer (score 1):

No, (unlike Java), when you declare the array, it creates a string at each index using the default constructor.

Edit for clarity:

by "new" I don't mean like the `new` allocation to the heap, it gets stored wherever you declared it, in the data section (for globals) or stack (locals).

---

From a comment, it seems you're thinking more of something like this:

```
std::string foo[3];
...
foo = {"a","b","c"}; // DOES NOT WORK
```

No, you can't do that.  `foo` already has its space allocated and initialized, and you can't just assign whole arrays like that (except in the initializer).  If you declared it as `std::string *foo` you could, but I don't recommend that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning C++ and I'm not very experienced, but I believe that is perhaps the best way if you wanted to initialize after the declaration. Or you could use a for loop for example to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++0x, you'll be able to use generalized initializer lists.  But it won't be much different from writing the assignments out longhand.

Do note, however, that in the case where you had a complicated expression repeated for each assignment (as K-ballo points out, the different between assignment and initialization is sometimes important, get in the habit of distinguishing):

```
ALongPointerName->ALongMemberName.ALongArrayName[0] = "T1";
ALongPointerName->ALongMemberName.ALongArrayName[1] = "T2";
ALongPointerName->ALongMemberName.ALongArrayName[2] = "T3";
```

you can use a reference to shorten that up:

```
auto& a = ALongPointerName->ALongMemberName.ALongArrayName;
a[0] = "T1";
a[1] = "T2";
a[2] = "T3";
```

which takes away much of the pain.