# c++ string array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, string, initialization

I know I can do this in C++:

```
string s[] = {"hi", "there"};
```

But is there anyway to delcare an array this way without delcaring `string s[]`?

e.g.

```
void foo(string[] strArray){
  // some code
}

string s[] = {"hi", "there"}; // Works
foo(s); // Works

foo(new string[]{"hi", "there"}); // Doesn't work
```

Comment: why would you use dynamically allocated c-style arrays? I would suggest you use `std::vector` instead. When using c++11 you can construct them using initialization lists, e.g. `void foo(vector<string>); foo({"hi", "there"});` should work in c++11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of strings initialization in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8021801/608639)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++11 you can. A note beforehand: Don't `new` the array, there's no need for that.

First, `string[] strArray` is a syntax error, that should either be `string* strArray` or `string strArray[]`. And I assume that it's just for the sake of the example that you don't pass any size parameter.

```
#include <string>

void foo(std::string* strArray, unsigned size){
  // do stuff...
}

template<class T>
using alias = T;

int main(){
  foo(alias<std::string[]>{"hi", "there"}, 2);
}
```

Note that it would be better if you didn't need to pass the array size as an extra parameter, and thankfully there is a way: Templates!

```
template<unsigned N>
void foo(int const (&arr)[N]){
  // ...
}
```

Note that this will only match stack arrays, like `int x[5] = ...`. Or temporary ones, created by the use of `alias` above.

```
int main(){
  foo(alias<int[]>{1, 2, 3});
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Prior to C++11, you cannot initialise an array using type[]. However the latest c++11 provides(unifies) the initialisation, so you can do it in this way:

```
string* pStr = new string[3] { "hi", "there"};
```

See http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#uniform-init

Answer (score 4):

With support for C++11 initializer lists it is very easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

using Strings = vector<string>;

void foo( Strings const& strings )
{
    for( string const& s : strings ) { cout << s << endl; }
}

auto main() -> int
{
    foo( Strings{ "hi", "there" } ); 
}
```

Lacking that (e.g. for Visual C++ 10.0) you can do things like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<string> Strings;

void foo( Strings const& strings )
{
    for( auto it = begin( strings );  it != end( strings );  ++it )
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}

template< class Elem >
vector<Elem>& r( vector<Elem>&& o ) { return o; }

template< class Elem, class Arg >
vector<Elem>& operator<<( vector<Elem>& v, Arg const& a )
{
    v.push_back( a );
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    foo( r( Strings() ) << "hi" << "there" ); 
}
```

Comment: Much too verbose: use a range-based loop: `for(auto s : strings) cout << s <<endl;`

Comment: @rwst: Yes, today it is. Thanks. I *probably* used iterators to support common Visual C++ in 2012. The simple loop you show has a slight inefficiency in that it copies strings but (1) that's insignificant compared to the io in the loop body and (2) it's anyway irrelevant, since it's not what this example is about, and (3) a rewrite for efficiency (not teaching bad idioms) is not hard to understand. So, as of 2015 I see no reason to keep the iterator loop I used. Feel free to fix. :)

Comment: @rwst: OK I updated it myself. Also checked that the Visual C++ 10 example actually compiles with VC10. When I looked at it now I couldn't remember that VC10 supported rvalue references, but, it did (at least the code compiles and produces correct result).

Comment: `using Strings = vector<string>` and `typedef vector<string> Strings` are so much unneeded and make reading code harder

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 and above, you can also initialize `std::vector` with an initializer list.  For example:

```
using namespace std; // for example only

for (auto s : vector<string>{"one","two","three"} ) 
    cout << s << endl;
```

So, your example would become:

```
void foo(vector<string> strArray){
  // some code
}

vector<string> s {"hi", "there"}; // Works
foo(s); // Works

foo(vector<string> {"hi", "there"}); // also works
```