# How do you split the string using specific number?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, split, numbers

I'm trying to split numbers using the specific digit "11". For example, "1110110011" is a string and I want to create an array of these strings like this, "11, 1011, 0011". Can anyone help me? I'm using C++ for this function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


vector<string> splitStrings(string str, char dl){
    string word = "";

    // to count the number of split strings 
    int num = 0;

    // adding delimiter character at the end 
    // of 'str' 
    str = str + dl;

    // length of 'str' 
    int l = str.size();

    // traversing 'str' from left to right 
    word = "";
    vector<string> substr_list;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        // if str[i] is not equal to the delimiter 
        // character then accumulate it to 'word' 
        if (str[i] == dl && str[i + 1] == dl) {
            //cout << str[i] << str[i+1] << endl;
            word += str[i];
            //substr_list.push_back(word);
            word += str[i + 1];
            //substr_list.push_back(word);
            str[i] = 0;
            str[i + 1] = 0;
            if (word != "1" || word != "0" ) {
                substr_list.push_back(word);
            }
            word = "";
        }
        else {
            word += str[i];

        }
    }

    // return the splitted strings 
    return substr_list;
}

int main(){
    string str1 = "1110110011";
    char dl = '1';
    int numberofsplitstring = 3;

    vector<string> result = splitStrings(str1, dl);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofsplitstring; i++) {
        cout << result[i]; //without space
    }
}
```

There is one flaw I don't know how to fix. My intention is to make sure when I printed the result, it still comes out "1110110011". However, when I implemented it in Visual Studios 2019, it outputted as "11 1011 0011". Therefore, when I add endl line, it outputted like this,

[This picture in this link. For the second and third element of the vector, 1011 and 0011 has an extra whitespace I needed to remove.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVeSQ.png)

Comment: Are you using an array of characters or an array of integers?

Comment: For now, I'm using vectors string.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something, but now I have to go. That's why I'm throwing you the part I've done so far. I hope you can continue from now on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


// Function accepts a string and
// checks if string can be split.
void split(string str, string keyword){
    int len = str.length();
    // if there is only 1 number
    // in the string then
    // it is not possible to split it
    if (len == 1) {
        cout << ("Not Possible");
        return;
    }
    string* splitted = new string[2030] {};
    std::string tempString = str;
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        std::string check(1, str[i]);
        check += str[i+1];


        if (strcmp(check.c_str(), keyword.c_str()) == 0){

            cout << "\nEqual." <<check.c_str() <<keyword.c_str() << endl;
            tempString.erase(i, i+1);
            cout << tempString << endl;
        }else {
            cout << "\nNot equal." <<check.c_str() <<keyword.c_str() << endl;
        }

    }
}


int main()
{
    string str = "1110110011";

    // Call the split function
    // for splitting the string
    split(str, "11");

    return 0;
}
```

You can check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdstringerase-in-cpp/) for erase function.
You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626722/c-string-array-initialization) for String Array

Answer (score -1):

Use string's [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method to find the position of the first match.

Add substring from the start index (0) to that position+1 (to account for the second '1')

Adjust search position and repeat.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the split function then add “11” back on the end of each list element

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Comment: OP  asked about a C++ solution, not python.